# UI-View scopes in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angular-ui-router

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/bb7DktwK9JkZDaWgNpYL?p=info

If you click on route 1 note that instead of two scopes (child and parent) the  adds an additional scope (visible if you inspect elements, look for ng-scope). What I'd like to do is store some data in the abstract parent state's scope (route 1) and make this available if I were to transition to, for example, route1.step2.

Currently I need to access this scope using $scope.$parent.$parent, which is less than ideal. Is there a neater way to either access the parent non ui-view scope or to prevent the ui-view tag from creating a scope between the child and parent ? I've tried setting explicit parent properties in the state declaration but it doesn't make any difference